# Phonegap SQLitePlugin returns [object HTMLHeadingElement] in IOS

Tags: ios, cordova, sqlite

I am developing IOS application using Phonegap 2.9.0 and xcode 5 testing in IOS simulator version 7.0.3

```
db.transaction(
    function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM tbl_chapter where chapter_id="+cid+" limit 1", [],
            function (tx, result) {

                    duaTitle = result.rows.item(0)['chapter_name'];
                    console.log("Print Result 1" + duaTitle);

            }, null);

    }, function(e) {
                   console.log("ERROR: " + e.message);
                   });
    console.log("Print Result 2" + duaTitle);
```

Log prints result 1 is proper

but print result 2 returns [object HTMLHeadingElement], only first time, and again when the function calls it works fine

Please help me to fix this

Thanks in advance,

Ali

Answer (score 0):

Define duaTitle variable (eg. var duaTitle=''; ) in this way where you initialise.